# Magento 2 extend $.mage.quickSearch Widget

Tags: magento2.2.2, search, catalogsearch, requirejs, component

I don't seem to be able to extend quick search module widget form-mini.js found in module/path: `../vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/web/form-mini.js`

How can I extend in my custom module `$.mage.quickSearch` Widget?

Already tried in `Vendor_Module/js/search`:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'matchMedia',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/menu'
], function($){

    $.widget('custom.quickSearch', $.mage.quickSearch', {
        _init: function () {
            alert("I'm here");
        }
    });

    return $.custom.quickSearch;
});
```

in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "quickSearch": "Vendo_Module/js/search"
        }
    }
};
```

I've previously successfully extended `$.mage.menu` Widget using the same technic as above but struggling with quick search does anyone know? help appreciated!

Comment: Are you facing any issue?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra the error was `Uncaught TypeError: base is not a constructor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use mixins way with the full path of js.

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Search/form-mini': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/mixins/form-mini': true
            }

        }
    }
};
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/mixins/form-mini.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'matchMedia',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, mediaCheck) {

    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('custom.quickSearch', widget, {
            _init: function () {
                alert("I'm here");
            }
        });
        return $.custom.quickSearch;
    };
});
```

[image]

Comment: Never used mixins before that is exactly what I need to know it works!

Comment: Instead of "Magento_Search/form-mini" it shoud be "Magento_Search/js/form-mini".